# c socket prog - select() problems

Tags: c, sockets, select-function

I'm new to network programming. I have to write a simple client/server program in C. The server will listen for a connection and the client will connect to the server, send a message, and receive an echo back from the client.  We have to update this using select() to handle connections to multiple clients at the same time from the server process.  I tried to implement select() on the client side like instructed,but I think I'm having an infinite loop on the client side in `if(FD_ISSET(clientSockfd, &readfds))` part.

```
//client1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


const int BUF_SIZE = 512;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buf[BUF_SIZE], buf2[BUF_SIZE];
    char *msg;
    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo;
    int clientSockfd, errorCheck, readVal, numfd;
    struct hostent *hostName;
    fd_set readfds;

    //make sure user entered correct arguments when starting client
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("error: must enter 'programName portNumber hostname'\n");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //create socket and error check socket() call
    clientSockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSockfd == -1)
    {
        perror("error creating socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //assign sockaddr_in info for RemoteAddr
    bzero(&serverInfo, sizeof(serverInfo));
    serverInfo.sin_family=AF_INET;

    hostName=gethostbyname(argv[2]);
    if(hostName == NULL)
    {
        herror("Error when calling gethostbyname()");
        exit(errno);
    }

    memcpy((unsigned char *) &serverInfo.sin_addr, (unsigned char *)hostName->h_addr, hostName->h_length); //copy IP address to be used
    serverInfo.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));       //port number to be used, given in command line, must be converted to network byte order

    //connect to server side
    if(connect(clientSockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverInfo, sizeof(serverInfo)) == -1)
    {
        perror("error when connecting to server");
        exit(errno);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);  //zero out set
        FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readfds);
        FD_SET(clientSockfd, &readfds);

        int maxfd = fileno(stdin);
        if(maxfd < clientSockfd)  maxfd = clientSockfd;
            numfd = select(maxfd, &readfds, 0, 0, 0);   //call select()

        if(numfd > 0)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(clientSockfd, &readfds))
            {
                //make sure buf is empty so it doesnt print extra chars
                bzero(buf2, BUF_SIZE);
                read(clientSockfd, buf2, BUF_SIZE);

            }
            if(FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &readfds))
            {
                bzero(buf, BUF_SIZE);
                fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE-1, stdin);
                printf("echo from server: %s\n", buf);
                errorCheck = write(clientSockfd, buf, strlen(buf)+1);
                if(errorCheck == -1)
                {
                    perror("error writing");
                }       
            }
        }
        else if(numfd == 0)
        {
            perror("Error using select()\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            printf("no data\n");
    }
    //close connection to server
    errorCheck = close(clientSockfd);
    if(errorCheck == -1)
    {
        perror("Error closing connection.");
        exit(errno);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is the server..

```
//server.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>


const int ASSIGNED_PORT = 17000;
const int BUF_SIZE = 512;

int main() {

    int serverfd, clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serverSock;      //NOTE: a pointer to sockaddr_in can be cast to a pointer to 
    //      a struct sockaddr - useful for connect()

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int errorCheck, msgLength;

    //create socket with error checking (-1 ret on error)
    serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serverfd < 0 )
    {
        perror("socket failed.");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //assign sockaddr_in info for server
    bzero(&serverSock, sizeof(serverSock));     //set to all 0's
    serverSock.sin_family = AF_INET;                
    serverSock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverSock.sin_port = htons(ASSIGNED_PORT);


    //bind a name to the socket with error checking (0 ret on success)
    errorCheck = bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverSock, sizeof(serverSock));
    if(errorCheck < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed.");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //listen for connections with error checking (0 ret on success)
    errorCheck = listen(serverfd, 10);
    if(errorCheck < 0 )
    {
        perror("listen failed.");
        exit(errno);
    }

    printf("Listening for connections.  Enter CNTRL-c to kill server.\n");

    //create infinite loop to accept, read, write, and close connections with error hecking 
    while(1)
    {

        //accept the connection from the client 
        clientfd = accept(serverfd, 0, 0);
        if(clientfd ==  -1)
        {
            perror("error accepting connection.");
            exit(errno);
        }

        //read data from the client
        bzero(buf, BUF_SIZE);
        msgLength = read(clientfd, buf, BUF_SIZE-1);
        if(msgLength == -1)
        {
            perror("error reading from client");
            close(clientfd);
            close(serverfd);
            exit(errno);
        }

        if(buf[0] '\0')
        {
            printf("connection closing");
            exit(0);
        }
        //print what the client sent
        printf("Message from client: %s\n", buf);

        //echo back what the client sent
        errorCheck = write(clientfd, buf, strlen(buf)+1);   

        if(errorCheck == -1 )
        {
            perror("error writing to client");
            exit(errno);
        }

        //close the connection
        errorCheck = close(clientfd);
        if(errorCheck == -1)
        {
            perror("error closing connection");
            exit(errno);
        }       
    }

    errorCheck = close(serverfd);
    if(errorCheck==-1)
    {
        perror("error closing server, exiting program now");
        sleep(6);
        exit(errno);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.  You have an extraordinary number of blank lines between every line.

Comment: A quick look revealed a few things: Is your `"/0"` supposed to be `"\0"` (two NUL characters)? Moreover, I think you want `if (buf[0] == '\0')` (note the single quote for char comparison) instead. Apart from that, `bzero` is deprecated, and `herror` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem (or at least, a problem) in your client-side code is that you are passing the magic number 32 to select().  That's incorrect.  What you should be passing is the maximum of all of the socket numbers, plus one.  For example, something like this:

```
int maxfd = fileno(stdin);
if (maxfd < clientSockFD) maxfd = clientSockFD;
// further maximizations for other sockets would go here, if you had any other sockets...
numfd = select(maxfd+1, &readfds, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: so, maybe what a good question would be is how i should test the client to see if the select function is working?  I think I just may be confused because everything I've looked at always implements select() on the server side and not the client.  So, I'm a little confused.  Also, when I send text strings on the client side, it limits me to sending only 3 before closing.  Why is this??

Comment: Oops, I made an error in my code snippet, the first argument to select should be maxfd+1, not just maxfd.  I'll edit my answer to correct.

Comment: As for why your client's socket gets closed, presumably that is because the server side is set up to just read a single stream from the TCP connection, and then close the TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `select()` on the server side to handle multiple clients, not on the client side.

Comment: select() can be helpful on either side of the connection, depending on what behavior is desirable.

Comment: i first had select() implemented on the server side and my teacher told me that it wasn't what he wanted and select should be in the client, not the server

Comment: Select can be useful anywhere you want a program to handle multiple socket fds at the same time.  It's most commonly used in servers, because servers typically want to be able to handle multiple client connections at the same time, but it can be useful in clients too (as in your case, where you want to handle receiving input on stdin and from a TCP socket simultaneously)

Comment: Makes sense.  I appreciate your help.  I believe I have finally got it working like my teacher wanted.  I was overthinking it too much.

Comment: @newuser12 what reason did your teacher advance for that bizarre requirement? It is back to front from common industry practice.

Comment: Basically, we just needed a way to 'read' both string the user entered and string the server sent.  The server was to echo the string the client sent back to the client.  It allowed us to send multiple strings using one client instead of send a string, get an echo, and close the connection right after.

Comment: Note that the select-on-stdin trick doesn't work under Windows, though :(

Comment: this isn't helpful and isn't true